# PrintWriter issue with even numbers

Tags: java, loops, printwriter

I'm having an issue here: I had this program printing all even numbers 0 through 1000 but after a friend made some changes it only prints "0" now. I've worked with it for a while and can't figure out if it's a loop issue or a printwriter issue. I took the loop out of the printWriter method and still nothing. What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class NumberWriter {


public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String fileName = "numbers.txt";





    try {
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);


        for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
            if (i%2==0){


        outputStream.println(i + "");
        outputStream.close();

        }
        }
    }


     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();



     }
}
    }
```

Comment: it seems you just closed the outputStream in the if.

Comment: What is that `i + ""` doing there??

Answer (score 2):

Don't close your [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close%28%29) (`outputStream`) or you won't get any more output. And your code can be optimized to increment by `2` and bypass the even test (this works because every even number is a multiple of two). And Java now has [The `try-with-resources` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) so you don't have to remember to close your `PrintWriter`,

```
try (PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName)) {
  for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i += 2){
    outputStream.println(Integer.toString(i));
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace():
}
```

Comment: You certainly *should* be closing it, just not *yet*.

Comment: @DavidConrad +1 Oops. Added `try-with-resources`.

Comment: Why not just using `println(i)`? It would end up invoking `Integer.toString(i)` anyway :)